# Unable to retrieve Analytics data for branded accounts using YouTube Analytics API

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to get analytics data for a brand account that I am the administrator of.

I am going to use Google Apps Script and YouTube Analytics API to retrieve the data.

I have done the following.

1. Creating Google Apps Script
2. Enabling YouTube Analytics API
3. Write the following code (This is a slightly modified version of the sample code in the following link. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics I put the ID of the brand account in the variable channelId because, as in the sample, the ID of my account channel, not the brand account channel, goes into the variable channelId.)

```
/**
 * Creates a spreadsheet containing daily view counts, watch-time metrics,
 * and new-subscriber counts for a channel's videos.
 */
function createReport() {
  // ========== Comment out from here ==========
  // // Retrieve info about the user's YouTube channel.
  // const channels = YouTube.Channels.list('id,contentDetails', {
  //   mine: true
  // });
  // const channelId = channels.items[0].id;
  // ========== Comment out so far ==========
  // ========== Added from here ==========
  const channelId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' // Fill in the channel id of the brand account here
  // ========== Added so far ==========

  // Retrieve analytics report for the channel.
  const oneMonthInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
  const today = new Date();
  const lastMonth = new Date(today.getTime() - oneMonthInMillis);

  const metrics = [
    'views',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'averageViewDuration',
    'subscribersGained'
  ];
  const result = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query({
    ids: 'channel==' + channelId,
    startDate: formatDateString(lastMonth),
    endDate: formatDateString(today),
    metrics: metrics.join(','),
    dimensions: 'day',
    sort: 'day'
  });

  if (!result.rows) {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
    return;
  }
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('YouTube Analytics Report');
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Append the headers.
  const headers = result.columnHeaders.map((columnHeader)=> {
     return formatColumnName(columnHeader.name);
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  // Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length,  headers.length).setValues(result.rows);

   Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
}

/**
 * Converts a Date object into a YYYY-MM-DD string.
 * @param {Date} date The date to convert to a string.
 * @return {string} The formatted date.
 */
function formatDateString(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

/**
 * Formats a column name into a more human-friendly name.
 * @param {string} columnName The unprocessed name of the column.
 * @return {string} The formatted column name.
 * @example "averageViewPercentage" becomes "Average View Percentage".
 */
function formatColumnName(columnName) {
  let name = columnName.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
  name = name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
  return name;
}
```

4. I tried to run the script in this state, but got the following error.

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtubeAnalytics.reports.query failed with error: Forbidden
createReport    @ youtube_analytics_api.gs:25
```

What can I do to resolve this error and get the API to run successfully?

Comment: Im confused are you using Google analytics, YouTube analytics, or the youtube data api?

Comment: Forbidden means you dont have access please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to use YouTube Analytics API, not Google Analytics API.

Comment: As you indicated, I will try to be more detailed in my questions.

Comment: YouTube.Channels.list  <-- is not a youtube analytics api method

Comment: I have edited the question to include a MINIMAL REPRODUCTIVE EXAMPLE

Comment: Where is your authorization code? Thats not a full example.

Comment: Do you mean that I need the authorization code to execute the above code?
I do not understand the following two points.


1. where can I get an authorization code?


2. where should the authorization code be incorporated in the code above?

Comment: How are you creating YouTubeAnalytics?  Where are you applying the authorization to it.   I cant run this without the coded needed to authorize the user you have only posted half your code.  You have not posted anything associated with authorization.   Your error is in your authorization code.   Post that.   [everything here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps#node.js)

Comment: I am running it with a Google Apps Script created from Google Drive. When I pasted the sample code from [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics) as is and executed it, it ran without any problems without authentication, but does this mean that authentication is additionally required in this case?

Comment: On the left you had to add drive in app script When you did that it requested authorization.    App script does it automatically.    Your question is about node.js not app script though.  Node.js needs to be authorized.